# Recursion - why use return statement

Tags: java, recursion

I am learning recursion and below is one example that I am tracing through to better understand it

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    new TestRecursion().strRecur("abc");
}

public void strRecur(String s) {
    if(s.length() < 6) {
        System.out.println(s);
        strRecur(s+"*");
    }
}
```

Below is what I have understood so far.
- In the first call to `strRecur("abc")`, the method gets added to execution stack. It prints "abc" before pausing due to a recursive call with parameter "abc*".

- The second call with "abc*", pushes method `strRecur(abc*)` to the stack and prints "abc*" to console.
- The third call with "abc**", pushes method `strRecur(abc**)` to the stack and prints "abc**" to console.
- The fourth call with "abc***", pushes method `strRecur(abc***)` to the stack. Since the base condition is met, the method completes (without printing anything) and pops out of the stack.
- The third call with "abc**" is completed and popped out. Since there is no pending code to execute nothing happens.
- The second call with "abc*" is completed and popped out. Since there is no pending code to execute nothing happens.
- The initial call with "abc" is completed and popped out. Since there is no pending code to execute nothing happens.

[image: Stack]

Prints following to the console -

```
abc
abc*
abc**
```

I think I understand what is happening here. Now, I want to try a slight variation of this code. Instead of calling`strRecur(s+"*")`, I would like to do `return strRecur(s+"*")`

```
public class TestRecursion {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        new TestRecursion().strRecur("abc");
    }

    public String strRecur(String s) {
        if(s.length() < 6) {
            System.out.println(s);
            return strRecur(s+"*");
        }
        return "Outside If";
    }
}
```

My expectation was that, once `strRecur(abc***)` pops out, it's output (abc***) would be returned to the next `strRecur()` on the stack, so I would see abc**** printed in the console. Same for other recursive calls as well.

However, the output in this case is exactly the same as when there is no return statement. My understanding (which of course is  not correct) stems from the recursive factorial implementation, where we do something like

```
return n * fact(n-1);
```

Here `fact(n-1)` is resolved with the returned value of `n`, once the previous method on the stack completes. Why doesn't return behave in the same way in this example?

Comment: [Runnable example](https://ideone.com/GTCArI) in case anyone wants to fiddle.

Comment: Just a quick word of advice: I found that when trying to understand recursion it helps if you print out the details of every call. For example start your recursive method with something like `System.err.println( "> strRecur s="+s);` and before returning, you do `System.err.println("< strRecur s="+s);`. Then you can trace what is being called with what input parameter and in what order. Maybe not with this relatively simple recursion, but when you get to learn about more complicated scenarios, this may help a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of both methods is produced by the `println` statements within the recursive method, which is why it is identical in both methods.

The value returned by the second method is not printed anywhere, which is why you don't see it displayed.

If you would print the result of the second method, you will see it is `"Outside If"`, since that's the output of the last recursive call, which is then returned by all the other method calls.

If you want the output to be `abc***`, you should

```
return s;
```

instead of

```
return "Outside If";
```

The full code would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new TestRecursion().strRecur("abc"));
}

public String strRecur(String s) {
    if(s.length() < 6) {
        return strRecur(s+"*");
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Additionally, and I don't know what OP's requirements are, you may need to change the 6 to 5. His first example only gets as far as `abc**`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make it return the value instead of printing it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = StrRecur("abc");
    System.out.print(result);
}

public static String StrRecur(String s) {
    if(s.length() < 6) {
        return s + "\n" + StrRecur(s+"*");
    }
    return "";
}
```

This does the same, but the side effect happens only in `main`.